# Problems when creating a new project with zendframework 3, using a Composer

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php, zend-framework3, php-7.4

Please i'm trying to learn the Framework Zend 3, even i know it is outdated framework but i should learn it because i have to use it in alternation in the company.

I am trying to follow the installation instructions detailed here (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zend_framework/zend_framework_skeleton_application.htm), and using the command :

```
composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application myPremAppZEND
```

but I get the following error after running composer update :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvsSQ.jpg)
here the problems without consulting image :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1

```
- Root composer.json requires zendframework/zend-skeleton-installer ^0.1.7 || ^1.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-skeleton-installer[0.1.7].

- zendframework/zend-skeleton-installer 0.1.7 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

Problem 2

```
- zendframework/zend-component-installer[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.1, 2.1.0, ..., 2.1.2] require composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.

- Root composer.json requires zendframework/zend-component-installer ^1.0 || ^2.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-component-installer[1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2].
```

Here i will post the file  **composer.json** :

```
{
"name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description": "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "mvc",
    "zf"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"require": {
    "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
    "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^2.1",
    "zendframework/zend-skeleton-installer": "^0.1.7 || ^1.0",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.1.1",
    "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.2"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "zend-skeleton-installer": [
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-developer-tools",
            "constraint": "^1.2.3",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install the developer toolbar?",
            "module": true,
            "dev": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-cache",
            "constraint": "^2.9.0",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install caching support?",
            "module": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-db",
            "constraint": "^2.10.0",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install database support (installs zend-db)?",
            "module": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-mvc-form",
            "constraint": "^1.0",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install forms support?",
            "module": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-json",
            "constraint": "^3.1.2",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install JSON de/serialization support?"
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-log",
            "constraint": "^2.11",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install logging support?",
            "module": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-mvc-console",
            "constraint": "^1.2.0",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install MVC-based console support? (We recommend migrating to zf-console, symfony/console, or Aura.CLI)",
            "module": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n",
            "constraint": "^1.1.1",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install i18n support?",
            "module": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-mvc-plugins",
            "constraint": "^1.0.1",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install the official MVC plugins, including PRG support, identity, and flash messages?",
            "module": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-psr7bridge",
            "constraint": "^1.2.0",
            "prompt": "Would you like to use the PSR-7 middleware dispatcher?"
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-session",
            "constraint": "^2.9.1",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install sessions support?",
            "module": true
        },
        {
            "name": "phpunit/phpunit",
            "constraint": "^5.7.27 || ^6.5.14 || ^7.5.17",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install testing support?",
            "dev": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-test",
            "constraint": "^3.3.0",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install MVC testing tools for testing support?",
            "dev": true
        },
        {
            "name": "zendframework/zend-servicemanager-di",
            "constraint": "^1.2.1",
            "prompt": "Would you like to install the zend-di integration for zend-servicemanager?",
            "module": true
        }
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "cs-check": "phpcs",
    "cs-fix": "phpcbf",
    "development-disable": "zf-development-mode disable",
    "development-enable": "zf-development-mode enable",
    "development-status": "zf-development-mode status",
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@development-enable",
        "php bin/update-gitignore.php"
    ],
    "serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public",
    "test": "phpunit"
}
```

}

Comment: There is no Zend framework but Laminas framework

Comment: @YourCommonSense as i explained first this company used zend framework 3 to developp an application and they still use it, so itried to create a new project but i had that problems in description

Comment: What did you try to resolve the problem? `zendframework/zend-skeleton-installer 0.1.7 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0`  looks pretty obvious to me: you try to install ZF using Composer v2, but ZF is not compatible with that. Use Composer v1

Comment: @NicoHaase you're right, I already solved the problem by migrating to version 1 of composer, thank you

Comment: That looks like a strange solution: keep in mind that Composer v1 is EOL

Answer (score 2):

I was forced to migrate to version 1.10 of Composer using the command:

`composer self-update --1`

and then I created my project normally with the command:

`composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install`